# Grouping the data according to table field

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table:

**BarcodeGroupMap:**

[image]

As we can see in the Groups field I have different groups and barcodeItem associated with it according to its EffectFrom date.

I just wanted to group barcode items according to Groups, but for same barcode item it should consider recent/max effectFrom date.

Output i desire:

```
Group  BarcodeItem   EffectFrom
1           1          2013-11-10
1           11        2013-11-14
1           22        2013-11-10 (max date amount 3 for barcode item 22)
1          222        2013-11-14
1          333        2013-11-14 
1         3331        2013-11-14
```

I made following query:

```
select * from BarcodeGroupMap bm ,

 ( 
  select groups,barcodeitem,bcgmid ,MAX(EffectFrom) as dates,CreatedDate as cdate from BarcodeGroupMap 
  group by groups ,barcodeitem,bcgmid,CreatedDate  having Groups=1 

 ) T 
 where t.Groups =bm.Groups and t.BarcodeItem = bm.BarcodeItem and  T.Groups =  1 and t.dates =bm.EffectFrom  Order by t.BarcodeItem , t.Groups
```

But Not Working. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
(
    SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groups, barcodeitem 
                                   ORDER BY effectfrom DESC, createddate DESC) rnum
      FROM BarcodeGroupMap m
     WHERE groups = 1
) t
 WHERE rnum = 1
 ORDER BY groups, barcode item
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ce9a/2)** demo

Comment: Sir, this is exact i wanted, but what if i will have to take data for effected date which is same ,then i want to take it according to max created date...means if effected date is same for particular barcode items, then it should take max(createddate) and give data...plz help

Answer (score 1):

```
select groups as [group], barcodeitem, max(EffectFrom) as EffectFrom
from BarcodeGroupMap 
group by groups, barcodeitem
order by groups, barcodeitem
```

Comment: I'm assuming the part of the question headed "Output i desire:" is a description of the desired output.